# How to make image pop up on a window Tkinter python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5

Hey I'm following a tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1Y5e-aGPQ4 , and I can't get it to work properly. I'm trying to add an image when you press on a menu button:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_Window()

    def init_Window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")

        self.pack(fill =BOTH, expand=1)

        #quitButton = Button(self, text = "Quit", command =      self.client_exit)
        #quitButton.place(x=0,y=0)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file=Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Save',command= self.client_exit)
        file.add_command(label='Exit',command= self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=file)

        edit = Menu(menu)
        edit.add_command(label='Show Image', command=self.showImg)
        edit.add_command(label='Show Text', command=self.showTxt)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Edit',menu=edit)

    def showImg(self):
        load = Image.open('Pic.png')
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0,y=0)

    def showTxt(self):
        text = Label(self,text='Hey')
        text.pack

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()



root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried asking around school, StackOverflow, and YouTube for about 3 days now, and nothing has solved my problem, if you need any more info about it please ask. I am getting the error code:

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1558, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File "/root/Desktop/Python Programs/Tkinter.py", line 35, in showImg
 load = Image.open('pic.png')
 AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

Comment: you use `import *` so you don't know if you use `tkinter.Image` or `PIL.Image` . And this is why you shouldn't use `import *`

Answer (score 1):

You use `import *` so you don't know if you use `tkinter.Image` or `PIL.Image` . And this is why you shouldn't use `import *`

Try

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

Comment: cannont import name ImageTk, I might have not installed PIL correctly, i am on linux so that may be an issue...

Comment: then use `pip install pillow`

Comment: Worked, got pillow 9.0.1, but is still git the issue cannot imort name 'ImageTk'

Comment: show full error message in question. Don't use `Tkinter` as your filename because `import` may try to import your file `Tkinter` instead of python module `Tkinter`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/Python Programs/Tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageTk'
>>>

Comment: rename `Tkinter.py` to something different - Maybe it help.

Answer (score -1):

Images are a bit tricky to get right, some tips: Keep the image object global, to avoid garbage collection, avoid Attribute Error (by reading the docs).

In this example I don t use PIL and I load a gif image

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*-coding:utf-8 -*

#Python 3
#must have a valid gif file "im.gif" in the same foldeer

from tkinter import *

Window=Tk()
ListePhoto=list()
ListePhoto.append(PhotoImage(file="im.gif"))

def Try():


    Window.title('image')
    Window.geometry('+0+0')
    Window.configure(bg='white')

    DisplayImage()

def DisplayImage():

    label_frame=LabelFrame(Window, relief='ridge', borderwidth=12, text="AnImage",
                         font='Arial 16 bold',bg='lightblue',fg='black')
    ListeBouttons=list()#Liste Vide pour les Radiobutton(s)

    RadioButton = Radiobutton(label_frame,text="notext",image=ListePhoto[0], indicatoron=0)
    RadioButton.grid(row=1,column=1)
    label_frame.pack(side="left")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    Try()
```